# grails json converter only returns strings not numbers, integers or doubles

Tags: json, grails

I have a database table that stores the structure of a simple table. The table contains user data.  The user can define how the table is set up.  Thus I store values and their types.  Everything is a string in the stored table. I need to pass this as JSON to the browser client, which does some JavaScript on the JSON. But, I want numeric values and string values in the JSON object, but the Grails JSON converter, only spits out Strings

My Service has:

```
def testMap(){
        //my results from a query
        List query = [["name":"price","value":"4.23","type":"double"],["name":"title","value":"box","type":"string"]]

        Map results = [:]
        query.each{ row ->
            if (row.type == "double"){
                results << [(row.name): row.value]
            }
            else
            {
                //what do I do here?
                results << [(row.name): row.value]
            }
        }        
        return results
    }
```

My Controller has...

```
def showMap(){
    render touchSourceSystemService.testMap() as JSON
}
```

The results are...

```
{"price":"4.23","title":"box"}
```

But I need the price to be numeric, not a string, like this.

```
{"price":4.23,"title":"box"}
```

Comment: `results << [(row.name): row.value as double]` in case of double?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this works. However, I've also got integer data, and if I put a `row.value as int` and I have a string with 4.25 in it, then i get a number format exception. the answer below by @Twelve24 allows me to just test to see if it's a string, otherwise do the other option and it handles the int an doubles just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue. The only way I could get it to work was like this...

Add this to top of your Service Class:

```
import groovy.json.*
```

And in your Service method, do this:

```
def testMap(){
    //my results from a query
    List query = [[name:"price",value:"4.23",type:"double"],[name:"title",value:"box",type:"string"]]
    def slrp = new JsonSlurper()
    def results = [:]
    query.each{ row ->
        if (row.type == "double"){

            //results << ["'${row.name}'": "${row.value}"]
            results  << slrp.parseText('{"' + row.name + '":' +  row.value + '}')
        }
        else
        {
            //what do I do here?
            results << slrp.parseText('{"' + row.name + '":"' + row.value + '"}')
            //results << ["'${row.name}'": "'${row.value}'"]

        }
    }        
    return results
}
```

Your controller should now return this:

```
{"price":4.23,"title":"box"}
```